# Интерактивность "длинных запросов"

Tags: javascript, golang

Есть веб сервер, в рамках сервера есть ряд утилит, выполненные в рамках запущенной горутины-менеджера, получающая управляющие команды через канал и в соответствии с командой, запускающему нужный пул горутин-воркеров. Воркеры выполняют задачи по типу `long-time query`, т.е. период выполнение которых может варьироваться от нескольких секунд до нескольких минут. Нужно этот процесс корректно отображать на html странице посредством JS, используя ajax. что-то "псевдоинтерактивности" по каждой запущенной горутине-воркеру отдельный блок div с контекстом текущего выполнения горутины (старт, обработка, конечная обработка, результат, завершение работы).  Какие адекватные кейсы есть для данного стека? Не прошу решения (сам реализую) просто общее описание работающих кейсов.

Comment: Добавляете отчетность по каждой из горутин в БД, к примеру, аналогично как это делает gearman, и потом выдаете эти данные на фронт. Хотя управление уже запущенной горутиной будет несколько проблематично, так как это делается уровнем выше. По сути вы делаете ту же задачу что тот же gearman, только в своей интерпретации.

Comment: Да, с бд вариант неплох только в случае статики (заранее известного количества задач, под каждую из которых потребуется воркер). В неопределенном  количестве целей-задач для воркеров (исходя из посыла одна задача = одна горутина-воркер, без разделяемой памяти) с учетом жестко прописанной структуры фронта - нашел решение в использовании вебсокетов, по наброскам должно работать должным образом. Клиент на фронте на js, сервер бэк - на go.